# Chrome translate issue under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

I live in Spain and Chrome normally offers me to translate into Spanish. 
I would rather have Chrome do the translation into English.
How may I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your default language from spanish to english.

http://www.dropmocks.com/mSlSb

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.